# Is nonexistence queriable in Datalog?

Tags: datalog

Suppose I've defined a few values for a function:

```
+(value[1] == "cats")
+(value[2] == "mice")
```

Is it possible to define a function like the following?

```
(undefined[X] == False) <= (value[X] == Y)
(undefined[X] == True)  <= (value[X] does not exist)
```

My guess is that it can't, for two reasons:

(1) Queries are guaranteed to terminate in Datalog, and you could query for `undefined[X] == True`.

(2) According to Wikipedia, one of the ways Datalog differs from Prolog is that Datalog "requires that every variable appearing in a negative literal in the body of a clause also appears in some positive literal in the body of the clause".

But I'm not sure, because the terms involved ("terminate", "literal", "negative") have so many uses. (For instance: Does `negative literal` mean `f[X] == not Y` or does it mean `not (f[X] == Y)`? Does `termination` mean that it can evaluate a single expression like `undefined[3] == True`, or does it mean it would have found all X for which `undefined[X] == True`?)

Comment: I really don't recognize the syntax.

Comment: It's almost all pyDatalog syntax, which might be a little nonstandard. The exception is `value[X] does not exist`, which is pseudocode.

Answer (score 1):

Here another definition of "safe".

> A safety condition says that every variable in the body of a rule must occur in at least one positive (i.e., not negated)
> atom.

Source: [Datalog and Recursive Query Processing](http://blogs.evergreen.edu/sosw/files/2014/04/Green-Vol5-DBS-017.pdf)

And an atom (or goal) is a predicate symbol (function) along with a list of terms as arguments. (Note that “term” and “atom” are used differently here than they are in Prolog.)

The safety problem is to decide whether the result of a given Datalog program can be guaranteed to be finite even when some source relations are infinite.

For example, the following rule is not safe because the `Y` variable appears **only** in a negative atom (i.e. `not predicate2(Z,Y)`).

```
rule(X,Y) :- predicate1(X,Z), not predicate2(Z,Y) .
```

To meet the condition of safety the `Y` variable should appear in a positive predicate too:

```
rule(X,Y) :- predicate1(X,Z), not predicate2(Z,Y), predicate3(Y) .
```